# In PHP, how do I use classes to pull data from my database and cache it?

Tags: php, class

I've been learning how to use classes, and I've been glancing through the Wordpress documentation and the files themselves, and I noticed all the database calls are done through a single class (WPDB).

I'm just curious how all this is done. It's kind of hard to see the forest for the trees when looking at Wordpress code, as it's so large.

I guess what I'm after is I want to create something like a "Page" object built around a class that pulls the appropriate page from the database and caches all the information for later use.

So far I've learned to create an abstract class that extends a basic enumeration class and contains constant values of my permissions, roles, tasks, etc. I **kind of** understand it. So, that's the level of understanding I have so far.

Comment: Well, it's unusual to have more than one class which manages database connections. You have one class which manages the open db connections and runs queries against it. So actually you just write a wrapper for MySQLi or PDO, so you won't have update every little piece of code when an extension gets deprecated and soon removes. Because with a class you do everything database related in that class. Changing a single class to use a new database extension is easier than changing the whole application code.

Comment: So I guess I'll be doing a construct with the initial database queries and pass cached objects to other classes/functions, but leave a public method for calling more queries? It's the overall structure I don't really understand. I'm working on building one just to see how it works at the moment.